# "Ce" s'accorde-t-il au pluriel, par exemple: "Ce sera/seront les filles qui s'occuperont de cela" ? Est-ce le cas pour tous les modes et temps ?

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, accord

La contruction ["ce"+verbe être] s'accorde-t-elle avec le nom qui suit dans tous les cas ? C'est-à-dire est-ce le cas avec tous les modes et temps ?

Par exemple :

- *ce seraient/serait*
- *que ce soit/soient*
- ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La phrase:

- **Les filles seront celles** qui s'occuperont de cela.

peut se transformer en la phrase suivante et garder le même sens:

- **Ce seront les filles** qui s'occuperont de cela.

On voit bien que filles et le verbe être s'accordent dans la première phrase et aussi dans la phrase transformée.

Le pronom **ce** ne s'accorde pas ici et c'est un *pronom démonstratif neutre:*

> *Ce* **accompagne le verbe être** qui *se met à la troisième personne du singulier ou du pluriel,* **tout dépend de ce qui suit (nom
> singulier, adjectif, proposition, ou nom pluriel).**

[leflepour curieux](https://leflepourlescurieux.fr/pronoms-demonstratifs-neutres-ce-ceci-et-cela-grammaire-b1/)

*Ce sera la fille* qui s'occupera de cela.
*Ce seront les filles* qui s'occuperont de cela.

Donc, "ce" est neutre et ne s'accorde pas. L'accord se fait avec le nom, etc. qui suit le verbe être. Par contre, l'accord se fait quand le pronom démonstratif a une fonction d'adjectif: ce, cette/s, ces, suivi d'un substantif.

Ce livre est excellent.
Ces livres sont excellents.

Answer (score 4):

Le pronom ***ce*** est identique au singulier et au pluriel.

Seul le verbe ***être*** est utilisable avec ***ce***, et uniquement aux troisièmes personnes du singulier et du pluriel.

> C'est lui
> Ce sont des voleurs
> C'étaient les autres
> Ç'aurait été dur

L'accord de *ce* avec un adjectif au féminin est exclu :

> *C'est beau* ✔
> *<s>C'est belle</s>* ✘

mais *ce* peut bien sûr être suivi d'un nom ou pronom féminin :

> *C'est elle* ✔

Même suivi d'un pluriel, le verbe *être* reste parfois au singulier :

> C'est nous ✔
> C'est eux ✔
> C'est des voleurs ✔ (relâché)

> Ce sera les filles qui s'occuperont de cela ***？*** (douteux : mélange de registres relâché et soutenu)
> Ce seront les filles qui s'occuperont de cela ✔ (soutenu)
> Ce/ça sera les filles qui vont s'occuper de ça ✔ (relâché)

Note : Ne pas confondre le pronom ***ce*** issu du latin vulgaire **ecce hoc* et l'adjectif démonstratif ***ce*** issu du latin *hic/ipse/ille*. Ce dernier s'accorde (ce/cet, cette, ces) mais il n'a rien à voir avec le pronom.

Answer (score 1):

Les formes de ce pronom démonstratif sont au nombre de trois : "*ce, c',ç'*" ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ce)). Il n'y a donc pas d'autre forme au pluriel que "ce".

*Example*

[image]

[ce seraient](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ce%20seraient%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)